# Validate a certain number of hasMany associated records in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.6.3.

I think this is best explained with an example.

I have a model, `Applicant`, and `Applicant hasMany Reference`. Most of the time, two references will be required for an applicant, but based on other input in the application form, a third reference may be required.

How can I require three or even two references? There doesn't seem to be any index key passed to the Reference model that allows me to link it up to which reference it is.

**In ApplicantsController**:

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is(array('post'))) {
            if (!$this->Applicant->saveAll($this->request->data, array('validate' => 'only'))) {
                // validation failed
            } else {
                if ($this->Applicant->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))) {
                    // data saved
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**In add.ctp Form**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Applicant');?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('Applicant.type');?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('Reference.0.name');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Reference.1.name');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Reference.2.name');?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end('Submit');?>
```

I know one method would be to make sure, in the view, that only the reference fields that are required are submitted with the data, and therefore only those required would be validated. But that means I wouldn't be able to *allow* three references to be entered and saved, but only *require* two.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly... you are looking for a way to validate only a certain number of references (based on other values passed with the form), for example only the first two, even when three or more are submitted? And vice versa, if the form requires three references, submitting only two of them should fail?

Comment: @ndm That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Might just try creating a [custom validation rule](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules).  If for some reason that doesn't meet your needs, you could use a `beforeSave()` callback to do any type of logic you want.

Either way, you should be able to save in a single `saveAll()`.